# Android Capturing Audio Stream and translating it into pcm data for effects

Tags: java, android, oop, audio, android-studio

How can I capture the audio stream in Android - (the music that is currently being played) and create a buffer so that I can add effects to it.

I plan on allowing the user to change the volume through the app as well as pitch.

Is something like this: [Increase volume output of recorded audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26088427/increase-volume-output-of-recorded-audio) going to work?

EDIT:

Some other Stackoverflow questions deal with taking the microphone input as the input of the audio stream. I would like to do something similar, but instead have the playing audio on the device be the input.

Comment: Capturing audio played by other apps is intentionally unsupported, as the system is designed to prioritize the wishes of content owners over those of device owners.

Comment: I believe it is blocked by the *stock* security model, yes.  For example the visualizer capability delivers only degraded samples.

Comment: I read that one can take the current audio stream and convert it to PCM data and add the desired events before outputting it.

Comment: I find it surprising that one could do that (at least on-device) as it is contrary to the clear overall design intent, but if you found clues you may be able to pursue them.