# How to increase amplify AudioTrack?

Tags: android, audio, audiorecord, audiotrack, android-audiorecord

I have the following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private int freq = 8000;
    private AudioRecord audioRecord = null;
    private Thread Rthread = null;

    int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;
    String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO};

    private AudioTrack audioTrack = null;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[freq];
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
        }

        android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);
        final int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(freq,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);


        audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, freq,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB, bufferSize);

        audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.ROUTE_HEADSET, freq,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB, bufferSize,
                AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

        LoudnessEnhancer enhancer = new LoudnessEnhancer(audioTrack.getAudioSessionId());

        enhancer.setTargetGain(100);
        enhancer.setEnabled(true);


        audioTrack.setPlaybackRate(freq);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        audioRecord.startRecording();
        Log.i("info", "Audio Recording started");
        audioTrack.play();
        Log.i("info", "Audio Playing started");
        Rthread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                        audioTrack.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

                    } catch (Throwable t) {
                        Log.e("Error", "Read write failed");
                        t.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        Rthread.start();
    }

    public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

This code is able to read input from the mic and play it back on a speaker/connected headphones. So far, so good. Now, I need to amplify the volume of the input. I've tried the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26088427/increase-volume-output-of-recorded-audio), but I just end up getting really distorted audio. I also tried the LoudnessEnhancer, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: audio is just a curve ... to increase volume you just multiply each point on the curve by some factor ... say 1.2 ... if not enought try 1.6, etc ... in sample code you refer to he is using a factor of 2 which may be too much for your audio ... be aware this stretching must be checked and clipped to max and min allowed value as defined by bit depth ... in your code above you are not showing where you are doing this point multiplication ... for a bit depth of 16 assure you pluck out two bytes of data to cut a fresh point avoid multiplying each byte separately .. also pay attention to endianness

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Perhaps distortion was the wrong term to use here. What I meant was that the audio keeps breaking up as it plays. It doesn't play as a continuous stream. Also, I do need quite a large amplification on the audio. Now, I'm not a sound engineer, and I'm very bad at low-level stuff, so a code sample would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, I managed to get the LoudnessEnhancer working. I know it's a huge gain value in there, but I need a lot of gain on this one. Here's the updated code for anyone else who might have a similar problem.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private int freq = 8000;
    private AudioRecord audioRecord = null;
    private Thread Rthread = null;

    int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;
    String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO};

    private AudioTrack audioTrack = null;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[freq];
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
        }

        android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);
        final int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(freq,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);


        audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, freq,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB, bufferSize);

        audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.ROUTE_HEADSET, freq,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB, bufferSize,
                AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

        LoudnessEnhancer enhancer = new LoudnessEnhancer(audioTrack.getAudioSessionId());
        NoiseSuppressor.create(audioTrack.getAudioSessionId());
        AcousticEchoCanceler.create(audioTrack.getAudioSessionId());

        enhancer.setTargetGain(10000);
        enhancer.setEnabled(true);


        audioTrack.setPlaybackRate(freq);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        audioRecord.startRecording();
        Log.i("info", "Audio Recording started");
        audioTrack.play();
        Log.i("info", "Audio Playing started");
        Rthread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                        audioTrack.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

                    } catch (Throwable t) {
                        Log.e("Error", "Read write failed");
                        t.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        Rthread.start();
    }

    public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```